# How can I get Google API to return a distance between two points on node.js and store it in a variable?

Tags: node.js, api, google-api

I am trying to get a distance between two locations with Google API, coding in node.js. I would like to store the value in a variable, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you know their names,You can try the following example which requests the distance matrix data between Washington, DC and New York City, NY, in JSON format

```
var request = require('request');
request.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=YOUR_API_KEY'

, function (error, response) {
     if(error){
         //Error handling
     }else{
        /*
            the response will be in a "JSON" format, you can see it in 
            details by entering the previous URL into your web browser 
            (be sure to replace YOUR_API_KEY with your actual API key) 
        */
     }
  })
```

or you can use this module [node-googlemaps](https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps) which wrap the apis.

if you know their longitudes and latitudes, i think there are no npm packages include the needed google libraries needed for that so i suggest you to calculate the distance by Haversine formula by using this npm module [Haversine formula](https://www.npmjs.com/package/haversine-distance) and this is a simple example:

```
var haversine = require('haversine-distance')

var a = { latitude: 37.8136, longitude: 144.9631 }
var b = { latitude: 33.8650, longitude: 151.2094 }

// 714504.18 (in meters) 
console.log(haversine(a, b))
```